# Old question: how to kill a thread immediately in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a chess game which allows two programs compete, the player needs to write a DLL and expose a function to tell the main application where this player will move in the next, suppose the function looks like

```
public static void MoveNext(out int x, out int y, out int discKind);
```

In the chess game application, I start a new thread to call the function that the player's DLL exposed to get where he will move in a turn, and I start a timer to prevent the player timeouts

```
 private Thread mPlayerMoveThread;

 private void SetPlayerToMove(IPlayer player)
        {
            this.CurrentPlayer = player;

            try
            {

                    System.Threading.Timer mTimeoutTimer = 
                                  new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimeIsUp), 
                                  null, 
                                  this.mMaxTimeOfOnePlayer, 
                                  Timeout.Infinite);

                    mPlayerMoveThread = new Thread(this.ThreadMethodPlayerAction);
                    mPlayerMoveThread.IsBackground = true;
                    mPlayerMoveThread.Start();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //// invalid move, so finish the game
                HandleInvalidMove(player.Color, ex);
            }
        }

 private void ThreadMethodPlayerAction()
        {
            this.CurrentPlayer.MoveNext();
        }

        private void KillThread(Thread thread)
        {
            if (thread == null || thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
                return;

            try
            {
                thread.Abort();
                thread.Join();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                thread = null;
            }

        }

        private void TimeIsUp(object state)
        {
            // kill the threads
            KillThread(mPlayerMoveThread);

            HandleInvalidMove(this.CurrentPlayer.Color, new Exception("timeout"));
        }
```

My questoin is:
  Can my function **KillThread** kill a thread correctly? If not, what should I do to stop the thead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Thread.Abort` is already bad practice because it throws a `ThreadAbortedException` at an arbitrary point. And it allows `finally` clauses to execute. So if there is an endless loop inside a finally it won't terminate the thread.

The right way is to unload the whole `AppDomain` containing that thread. Load each player's dll in its own `AppDomain`. That way you can force-unload it when you want without corrupting the state of the main application.

Comment: I like the idea of 'AppDomain', and would you give me some simple codes to indicate how to do that?

Comment: I haven't worked with them myself yet. But `Hosting` and `AppDomain` should give some search results. And if you need sandboxing I recommend looking into the .net 4 model, it's much easier than the older models.

Answer (score 0):

Killing a thread is possible but a very bad methodology. Why not just ask your players to supply an "Abort" function to the DLL? You can do it but adding it to your interface. Abort might not stop a thread if the player catches the ThreadAbortException and do nothing with it.

Comment: The exception is rethrown after the `catch` block exits. So he can't really catch it like other exceptions. But of course if the `catch`/`finally` block doesn't exit the thread won't terminate.

Comment: Why not just ask your players to supply an "Abort" function to the DLL? ---- Suppose there is a endless loop in the player's function 'MoveNext', then how the 'Abort' function supplied by player cound exit?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will probably kill the thread, but it's not absolutely guaranteed. For example, as the thread you're trying to kill rewinds up its call stack, it'll execute any finally blocks - so you're dependent on the code in those not hanging. Since your question seems to imply that the code the thread is running will have been written by someone else, and the person writing it may well not have anticipated attempts to abort the thread, you'd be unwise to rely on the thread behaving well. (You'd also be unwise to rely on the code being well written enough to clean up all resources it might hold before the thread terminates)

If you want an absolute 100% guarantee of being able to kill the thread that's calculating the move, I believe the usual way to get that is to have a separate process host the thread - then you can kill the process. But that presumes you don't mind the performance hit from starting a new process every time you need a move calculated.